# How should I rig this type of eyelids

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm new to 3D stuff and learning it using Blender(3.4). I downloaded a character from the internet to use it for learning. But I'm stuck at rigging eyelids.
I have spent a week or so to get them to work but no luck. Searched a lot and tried a lot too. I'm using rigify for rigging. Please see the images.[image: here] & [image: here] & [image: here]

What I'm trying to do right now is to have bones(tips) that can rotate from lid edge to top (near eyebrow). But this is not a spherical eyelid. That's causing me problems. How would you place bones such that their tips follow the eyelid curve(or surface) from eyelid edge to top (just below the eye brow)?
Right now, I'm concerned with top lid only.

Thank you.

Comment: Blinking (and facial movement) is mostly done with shape keys. Do you have any reason to not use it in this case?

Comment: I heard many people say it is easier and better than shapekeys. Maybe they meant that in case of spherical eyes. Haven't seen anyone doing this shape of eyelid with bones.